Relative button contains modal with button and it causes validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a descendant of <button>
I have button, which looks like 3 dots to open modal with 2 other buttons.
Should I make this 3 dots button just a div? What is the best decision so code will be semantically corrent?
jsx file:
<button className="reservations-item-button" 
     onClick={()=>setModal(s=>!s)} 
     style={{background:'none', border:'none'}}>
  <svg style={{margin: "auto 0"}} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       width="30" height="6" viewBox="0 0 30 6" fill="none">
    <circle cx="3"  cy="3" r="3" fill="#EDEFEE"/>
    <circle cx="15" cy="3" r="3" fill="#EDEFEE"/>
    <circle cx="27" cy="3" r="3" fill="#EDEFEE"/>
  </svg>
  {modal 
    ||
  <div className="reservations-item-modal">
    <button style={{background:'none', border:'none'}}>
      Edit
    </button>
    <button style={{background: 'none', border: 'none'}}>
      Delete
    </button>
  </div>
  }
</button>

CSS file:
.reservations-item-button{
    position: relative;
}

.reservations-item-modal {
    /*border: 1px solid rgb(255, 199, 0);*/
    background-color: #51724B;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: end;
    justify-content: end;
    position:absolute;
    top:18px;
    right:0px;
}

.reservations-item-modal button{
    color:#EDEFEE;
}


"What is the best decision so code will be semantically corrent?" - probably to separate the button, and the modal content. Write your own click handler for the button, that then calls the JS method to show the modal.

semantically correct should about using a <dialog> element (with .showModal() method)

Please try the below code:enter code here
Shobana: Programming makes sence
<button 
  className="reservations-item-button" 
  onClick={() => setModal(s => !s)} 
  style={{background: 'none', border: 'none'}}
  aria-label="Open options">
  <svg style="{{margin: "auto 0"}} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="6" viewBox="0 0 30 6" fill="none">
    <circle cx="3"  cy="3" r="3" fill="#EDEFEE"/>
    <circle cx="15" cy="3" r="3" fill="#EDEFEE"/>
    <circle cx="27" cy="3" r="3" fill="#EDEFEE"/>
  </svg>
</button>


What's the meaning of "Shobana: Programming makes sence"? and why have you included a code placeholder?
